# Does Phusion Passenger start a new Ruby instance for each visitor?

Tags: ruby, passenger, phusion

I'm very new to Phusion Passenger. I just know it keeps a limited number of worker threads, and shuts them down after a hour or so of inactivity.

But does it start a new Ruby instance for every request that comes in? Wouldn't that pose a problem if there are multiple users using my app? Is it beneficial to keep around as many instances as possible up and running, so I don't run into any performance issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please read this document:

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Architectural%20overview.html#_spawning_and_caching_of_code_and_applications

Simply said, it does not create ruby instance for every request, because it is not CGI.

I hope this helps.